# Accept POST from other application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter User Panel and a login form out of CodeIgniter Environment and I need to know how can I accept the post coming from this.

Basically, is:

My app send a POST with (login an password) to CodeIgniter application to login in successfully.

**Obs:** I read about CrossDomain POST with AJAX but doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/cp/login/auth',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {login: $('#login').val(), passwd: $('#passwd').val()},               
        })
    });
```

But when I click in submit button, I redirect to login page (CI) but don't log in.

I appreciate your patience. Thank you!

Comment: please share something you have tried so far, to get a more clear picture of your requirement!

Comment: the question is not clear, and is ambiguous at some degree. Can you please explain the purpose, how many servers do you have, and what want to achieve? If you'll keep like that - you'll have down-votes, as the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this header to your page. (http://localhost/cp/login/auth page)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: I use this header, but after click in submit button, still redirect to login page and not log in.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you add more code or send me a test URL.

Answer (score 0):

Say No for crossdomain ajax. Send data with post. And in your application check data and login user or redirect back if has errors.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you are trying to send data from ajax to a codeigniter function via post. Then you should do this:

```
function makeAjaxCall(){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "MyController/Myfunction',
    cache: false,               
    data: $('#MyForm').serialize()});       }
```

The form should be as

```
<form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" action="">
```

Submit Button as

```
<input type="button" onclick="makeAjaxCall();" value="Submit"/>
```

Then on the controller

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller{
public function Myfunction(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username_field');
    $password = $this->input->post('password_field');
    //Do my stuff then redirect
}}
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get info from other login app, you need to make a webservices or using curl

assuming that you app that make login and return data is working fine

in the other app, you need to make a call using curl like

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "username:password@example.com/controller/method/parm1/param2"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch); 

    //print result
    var_dump($output);
```